# react-tabs Tablist from a separate component

Tags: reactjs, react-table

In my application I am using `react-tabs` for creating tab navigation. It works very fine when the `TabList`:

exist inside Tab component like below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Tab, Tabs, TabList, TabPanel } from 'react-tabs';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Tabs>
          <TabList>
            <Tab>Title 1</Tab>
            <Tab>Title 2</Tab>
            <Tab>Title 3</Tab>
          </TabList>
          <TabPanel>
            <h2>Any content 1</h2>
          </TabPanel>
          <TabPanel>
            <h2>Any content 2</h2>
          </TabPanel>
          <TabPanel>
            <h2>Any content 3</h2>
          </TabPanel>
        </Tabs>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

But in my project I have a requirement like the `Tablist` will be returned from another component like below. In that case it is not working:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Tab, Tabs, TabList, TabPanel } from 'react-tabs';

const List = () => {
  return (
      <TabList>
        <Tab>Title 1</Tab>
        <Tab>Title 2</Tab>
        <Tab>Title 3</Tab>
      </TabList>
  )
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Tabs>
          <List />
          <TabPanel>
            <h2>Any content 1</h2>
          </TabPanel>
          <TabPanel>
            <h2>Any content 2</h2>
          </TabPanel>
          <TabPanel>
            <h2>Any content 3</h2>
          </TabPanel>
        </Tabs>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

How to solve above issue?

Comment: Either move the new List component to a new file and import it later on or replace <List /> with {List} and try again.

Comment: @SamuilIlkov ,tried that also.but doesn't work